# How do I create a trigger on multiple keys on sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

As far as I am aware, there's no direct ability to have foreign key constraints in SQLite 3.  I have a many-to-many table that needs this, so I'm creating a trigger that raises an ABORT when the foreign key constraint is violated.  My statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fkFooBar
  BEFORE INSERT ON Foo_Bar
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE (ABORT, 'Insert on Foo_Bar violates foreign key')
    WHERE ((SELECT id as fId FROM FOO WHERE fId = NEW.fooId) IS NULL) || ((SELECT id as bId FROM BAR WHERE bId = NEW.barId) IS NULL);
  END;
```

But this only constrains on the barId being present, not the fooId.  I'm only vaguely familiar with SQL, and haven't dealt with triggers before, so I'm a little lost on this.  Why doesn't this work?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Should this be much simpler? (i.e. in one SELECT statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody else actually answered the *question* I was asking:

|| is not a binary OR in sqlite.  Just use a single |

Answer (score 0):

Take the hint.

Triggers are usually a bad idea.  You've uncovered yet another reason why triggers are often a mistake.

The primary reason is that triggers break your programming into two pieces.  The code that is code -- and is easy to find and maintain -- and the code that is hidden in the database and is much more difficult to find and maintain.

If it's really hard to do, you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: Code.  Plain old code.  What language is your application written in?  Use that language.  If you have an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) layer, your "trigger" code goes in there, not the database.